# Count amount of time a number appears in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have a dice rolling function. I want to roll 2 dice 20 times, each time I roll, I want to add those numbers, and then I want to see how many times the sum appears, and put that number into an array.

```js
function Dice() {
  this.roll = function() {
    var randomValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    this.side = randomValue;
    return this.side;
  }
}

var dice1 = new Dice();
var dice2 = new Dice();

function getAmount() {
  var finalArray = [];

  function diceSum() {
    var sum = dice1.roll() + dice2.roll();
    return sum;
  }

  var trackSum = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    trackSum.push(diceSum());
  }


  var reduced = trackSum.reduce(function(acc, sum, i, arr) {
    return acc.i += sum;
  }, {});
  return reduced;
}
```

so I get `trackSum` which has 20 numbers in an array which, each number is the sum of the 2 dice rolled. If `sum = 2` and it appears 5 times, `sum = 4`, appears 2 times, `sum = 3`, appears 1 time, final array should look like

```
[5, 2, 1]
```

So far I tried a `reduce` method, `filter`, and `forEach`. I just can't figure out how to compare the numbers to see how many times it's appearing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you care about keeping track of the order of the rolls/sums? Or do you just want to know the number of times each sum occurred?

Answer (score 3):

Use an object whose keys are the sums, and values are the number of times the sum appears. Loop through `trackSum` and increment the value of the corresponding element.

```
var freq = {};
trackSum.forEach(function(sum) {
    freq[sum] = freq[sum] ? freq[sum] + 1 : 1;
}
console.log(freq);
```

Comment: I would not use `freq[sum]++` in an expression that is assigned to the same variable. It is confusing. Maybe `(freq[sum] || 0) + 1;`

Comment: I meant to write `+ 1`, not `++`, fingers typed too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering my own question, but after some googling, I figured it out. So don't pay attention to the reduce method I have in my original post. This is what I did instead:

```
var countedSum = trackSum.reduce(function(emptyObj, sum, i, arr){
      if (sum in emptyObj){
        emptyObj[sum]++
      } else {
        emptyObj[sum] = 1
      }
      return emptyObj;
    }, {});
```

This returns an object, with the sum value as the key, and the amount of times it happens as the value.

Then I learned a new method that grabs the values and puts it in an array.

```
Object.values(countedSum)
```

That solves it!

Thanks @Barmar for your help!